# Create gradient on div css3

Tags: css, gradient

I need to create gradient that will be in the bootom of element and look like this

[image]

I have tried like this

```css
.div-with-shadow {
  padding-bottom: 1.4285714286rem;
  border-bottom: solid 0.0714285714rem rgba(0, 0, 143, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3.5714285714rem 3.5714285714rem -3.5714285714rem #e9e9fd;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-with-shadow"></div>
```

But it does not look the same, this has to be some kind of gradient and not border, anyone can help me, thanks

Comment: your image is very hard to see .. it's almost white for me

Comment: I know that is the problem :(

Comment: use different color so we can clearly see the shape of the gradient then you can can later change with any color you want